# Expand listview item to new fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, material-design

I want to expand a listview item to a new fragment, so that the list view expands vertically into a fragment.

FragmentA

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:divider="#EEE"
    android:id="@+id/list_view_offer"></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

FragmentB

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
   ></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When a list a item is clicked the list item will expand to the relative layout in fragment B.

I have looked at a recycler view, and shared element activity transition.
But how do i do this when transition from one fragment to another fragment.

I am not able to use FragmentTransaction as i have to put the OnItemClickListner from the first Fragment(FragmentA).